# How to write map/route for multiple Post

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi I have an API Controller which required multiple POST :

one for Save/Update :

```
public Order PostOrder(Order order)
{

}
```

And, another for Search Order

```
public IQueryable<Order> SearchWithParameter(SearchOrderParameter searchParameter)
{

}
```

I have added below Route method in Global.asax

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SearchWithParameter",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{searchParameter}",
            defaults: new { action = "post" }
        );
```

In Js I am calling it as :

```
 var SearchOrderParameter = new Object();
 SearchOrderParameter.OrderID = 1197;
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9003/api/orders/SearchWithParameter",
    data: SearchOrderParameter,
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (value) {
        alert(value);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
 });
```

But every time this method calls `PostOrder`. Please guide me, What I am missing, so that it will call `SearchWithParameter`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using these routes...

```
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { action = @"^[A-Za-z]" }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

By default HTTP operations are mapped to a C# function starting with the HTTP method name. So an HTTP POST is going to be mapped to a Post....() method and never to a Search....() method. You can add an `HttpPost` attribute to make the SearchWithParameter() method also work with post.